# My Routing not working using useNavigate. how do i solve this issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Hey can someone please explain what is wrong in my code. i am trying to Route my path and link it using useNavigate. but its not working, URL changed but output was as it is. i will show my code

APP.js -- in this file i am using Routes, Routes\

```
import React from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Apps from './Apps'
import Lists from './Lists'


function App() {
  return (
   <div className='App'>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Apps/>}/>
      <Route path='/lists' element={<Lists/>}/>
    </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

APPS.js -- in this file i was using useNavigate

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Form1 from "./form1";
import Form2 from "./form2";
import { Box, Paper, Button } from "@mui/material";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ArrowForwardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward";

function Apps() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    gender: "",
    address: "",
    hobby: "",
    email: "",
  });

  let arr = [];

  const handleOnChange = () => {
    arr = [formData];
    console.log("arr", arr);
  };

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            "& > :not(style)": {
              m: "auto",
              width: 250,
              height: 485,
              marginTop: "50px",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Paper elevation={20}>
            <div className="App">
              <AccountCircleIcon
                fontSize="large"
                style={{ color: "#1976D2", marginTop: "10px" }}
              />
              <h1
                style={{
                  color: "#1976D2",
                  marginTop: "10px",
                  marginBottom: "10px",
                }}
              >
                Form Data
              </h1>
              <Button onClick={() => navigate("/lists")} variant="contained">
                <ArrowForwardIcon />
                List
              </Button>

              <Form1 formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />

              {formData.gender === 2 && (
                <Form2 formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
              )}
              <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={handleOnChange}
                >
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </Box>
      </React.Fragment>
    </>
  );
}

export default Apps;
```

Lists.js -- which i want to Route as result

```
import React from 'react'

function Lists() {
  return (
    <div>Lists</div>
  )
}

export default Lists
```

Comment: The "List" button and `navigate` call seems to work as expected in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-routing-not-working-using-usenavigate-how-do-i-solve-this-issue-4zghot).  Perhaps the issue is elsewhere. Are there any errors? What are the *exact* steps to reproduce the issue you see? Can you fork the sandbox and add more of your *actual* code to see if the issue can be reproduced there, and if so, provide us a link to the sandbox that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Working brother, Thank you so much. its just mistake made by me. its import mistake of App.js in index File.